# How to identify user inserting data in a netezza table

Tags: netezza

Is there a way to identify which user inserted/modified a particular row in a netezza table? The table is open to a group of user and I need to track (for auditing purpose) who inserted each row before using that data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you enable AUDIT history collection (one of the best Netezza features apart from raw performance) it is possible to trace back from the InsertXID of each record